# running a background process using a double fork?

Tags: shell, unix, fork

```
pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0 && background == 1){
              // performs background process
        pid2 = fork();
        if(pid2 == 0){
                        // grandchild process
        } else {
                        // child process
          exit(0);
        }
    } else if(pid == 0){                                    
              // child process
    } else {
              //parent process
       waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);

    }
```

My question is I'm trying to perform a background process using double forks but I'm not 100% sure it works or not with the way I set it up, another question is after I double fork what is a good way to handle the orpaned children, can I just leave them or will that cause an issue? this is for a unix shell.

Comment: Do you want to fork a `Daemon Process`?

Comment: pretty much I want to make it so I can list all background process and kill them if they are still running if need be.

Comment: basically implement this with the jobs command?

Comment: If you double-fork the children, as soon as the middle (child) process exits, they are already orphaned and owned by the master process (PID = 1) that gets to own orphaned processes.  There is no trivial way to track the processes after the double-fork, either.  You can also look at `setsid()` and `setpgrp()` and related functions.

Comment: For a shell, you probably only want to fork once.  The GNU C library manual contains a [detailed worked example of implementing a shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/index.html#toc_Processes) -- read *all* of the "Processes" and "Job Control" sections.  (Except you can ignore the "Job Control is Optional" bit.  *Those* systems have long since gone the way of the dinosaurs.)